# node.js golang composite architecture for web application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-ec2, go

I am currently architecting a web app that will use node.js for basic routing. Some parts of the app are more processor intensive and I wanted to use golang for those parts. However, I'm not sure the best way to install and communicate between the two languages. I'm using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk for initial tests, so any specifics can be targeted for that platform.

In essence it boils down to the following 2 questions:

1) How do you install both node.js and a golang docker image on Amazon EC2? Amazon has guides for one or the other, but not both.

2) What is the best way to offload processor intensive tasks from node.js to a golang codebase (I could imaging RPC, or just running golang on some localhost port, but I'm new to this type of thing)? The golang tasks might be things like serious number crunching or complex graph searches.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Why not have Go do the routing as well and simplify your design?

Comment: If you are going to use two different languages, it will be much easier using something like nginx in front to proxy the requests to each service. This would also take care of the basic routing so no traffic has to go to golang or node and get routed to the other.

Comment: OK, on EC2 with the default node.js setup, nginx is already used so I could use that to send certain requests to different ports (node.js listen on one port and golang on another port). But, are there other options, for instance if I wanted to call directly from node.js to golang?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, I would do everything in Go if it was my choice, but node.js is just faster to get something quick started with and I'd like the option of then offloading these processor intensive tasks as time goes on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go is trivial to deploy. Just build it on a linux box (or use gox) and deploy the binary. (You don't need go installed on the server to run a go program)
2. There are many options for communicating between Go and Node.js. Here are a few:

   1. If the work you are doing takes a long time it may not be appropriate to have the user wait for a response. For background tasks you can use a queue (like Redis' [rpoplpush](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) or a real queue like Kafka or RabbitMQ, or since you're using Amazon: [SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/)). Push your job as a JSON object onto the queue, then write a Go program that pulls from the queue, does its processing and then writes the final result somewhere.
   2. Go has a [jsonrpc library](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/jsonrpc/). You can communicate over TCP, serialize a request in Node, read it in Go, then deserialize the response in Node. It's the jsonrpc 1.0 protocol and for TCP all you have to do is add some message framing (prefix your json string with a length) or just newline separate each request / response.
   3. Write a standard HTTP service in Go and just make HTTP calls from NodeJS. (PUT/POST/GET)